# How to change RadGrid’s GridButtonColumn Confirmation Dialog Ok and Cancel buttons text for different languages

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have a Radgrid with a GridButtonColumn set up for Delete.  I am using the confirmation dialog and setting up the ConfirmText and ConfirmTitle properties according to the user’s language using resource files.  How can I get to the Ok button, Cancel button and the Close tooltip in the confirmation dialog so I can set it up accordingly to the users language?

Answer (score 0):

For that you must have to create your own Confirmation Template.

First of all you have to add one hiddenfield in your page That store your culture information. (if possible than put this code in master page so its work in every page).

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    HtmlInputHidden hi = new HtmlInputHidden();
    HtmlHead head = (HtmlHead)Page.Header;
    hi.ID = "HtmlInputHiddenLang";
    hi.Attributes.Add("class", "HtmlInputHiddenLang");
    hi.Value = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
    head.Controls.Add(hi);
}
```

Then after Create your own Theme or template for radwindowmanager.

```
 <telerik:RadWindowManager runat="server" SkinID="CustomSkin">
        <ConfirmTemplate>
            <div class="rwDialogPopup radconfirm">
                <div class="rwDialogText">
                    {1}
                </div>
                <div class="rwDialogButton">
                    <a onfocus="RadWindowConfirm_DefaultFocus();" onclick="$find('{0}').close(true);"
                        class="MyrwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <img id="Img2" runat="server" class="imgCurrentCulture" src="~/Images/CURRENT_CULTURE/Yes.png"
                            onmouseover="ImageButtonMouseOver(this);" onmouseout="ImageButtonMouseOut(this);" /></a>
                    <a id="hrefNo" name="hrefNo" onclick="$find('{0}').close(false);" class="MyrwPopupButton"
                        href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <img id="Img3" runat="server" class="imgCurrentCulture" src="~/Images/CURRENT_CULTURE/No.png"
                            onmouseover="ImageButtonMouseOver(this);" onmouseout="ImageButtonMouseOut(this);" /></a>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $('img.imgCurrentCulture').each(function () {
                        var culture = $('.HtmlInputHiddenLang')[0].value;
                        this.src = this.src.replace('/CURRENT_CULTURE/', '/' + culture + '/');
                    });

                    function RadWindowConfirm_DefaultFocus() {
                        document.getElementById("hrefNo").focus();
                    } 
                </script>
            </div>
        </ConfirmTemplate>
    </telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

As Per above code default url is like "~/Images/CURRENT_CULTURE/Yes.png".
Once you set your culture name in hidden field it was replaced CURRENT_CULTURE to En_us so your final image url is "~/Images/en_us/Yes.png".

Note : I used jquery in my code so not forget to add jquery in your project.